# Seting up Crontab in Ubuntu 18.4 Problem

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a server running PassBolt password manager and I have trouble setting up Cron properly for it to send automatic emails. Basically how it works is that whenever you need automatic email (say after registration...) it stores them and then execute them running the script, with absolute path (just in case) script would go as:

```
cd /var/www/passbolt/bin && ./cake EmailQueue.sender
```

What I want is to setup Cron to send it every minute or better yet every 10 seconds ( server performance is not an issue as software is used by the very small team. My Crontab (crontab -e) goes as follows:

```
1 * * * * /var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender
```

And it kinda works, but it doesn't send emails regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron time spec `1 * * * *` means every **hour**. The `1` means: every 1 minute passed the hour, i.e.  00:01,  01:01,  02:01, ... etc.

Use this to have it run every **minute**:

```
* * * * * /var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender
```